# Android: How to scroll viewflipper along with listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, viewflipper

In listview_main.xml file I have viewflipper and listview inside RelativeLayout. When I scroll the listview, viewflipper doesn't scroll along with the listview. Viewflipper overlaps listview.

I want viewflipper to scroll along with listview OR when I scroll listview I want viewflipper to be overlapped by listview. Either one will work.

I have searched for solutions the whole day but I couldn't find any. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/flipper" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_below="@id/flipper"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Search " Parallax Scrolls in android". Good effects with small coding. You will get Free libraries also.

Comment: @UmeshChhabra I tried Parallax Scroll, but I can't seem to make it work. Can you explain how it works and how I can implement it? I just want the viewflipper on top of the listview to scroll along with the listview. I can only scroll listview right now, whereas, the viewflipper remains fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I added viewflipper as a header view to listview and it worked. Now, when I scroll the listview the viewflipper scrolls with it.

I created two different xml files for viewflipper (listview_header.xml) and listview (listview_main.xml). Then, I added viewflipper to listview as header view.

**listview_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/flipper" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**listview_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_below="@id/flipper"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code to add viewflipper(listview_header.xml) to listview(listview_main.xml) as a header view.**

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup listviewHeader = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header, listview, false);

//add header view to listview
listview.addHeaderView(listviewHeader, null, false);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, arrayList);

//Set adapter
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this helps someone facing the same problem.